# How to pass data from parent RadMultiPage to dynamically filter combobox on child RadPageView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, telerik

We have inserted a Telerik RadMultiPage control on a webpage which has 7 tabs in it.
On some of those tabs, we'd like to display a combo box which will show the user a list of table names they can choose from to edit/view data.
We'd like that list of table names to be filtered based on the tab selected.

Is there some way to pass values from the page that hosts the RadMultiPage control to the child webpages for each RadPageView?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the ContentUrl to load entire pages in the PageViews,

- use a querystring parameter or Session/Cache variable (you can apply it in a similar fashion as the other answer)
- OR use JavaScript to call a function on the parent page that will return the needed data, something like

  ```
      //in the multiplage content page
      function getCurrentTab() {
          var info = window.parent.getActiveTab();
      }

      //on the page with the tab strip
      function getActiveTab() {
          var ts = $find("<%=YourTabStrip.ClientID%>");
          return ts.get_selectedTab().get_value();
      }`enter code here`
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea for you to consider. What you probably need is to register a tab click event on the server, and then pass this tab value into your drop down list control and then filter and rebind the data.

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" OnTabClick="RadTabStrip1_TabClick" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1">
  <Tabs>
    <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Tab1" Value="1" PageViewID="PageView1">
    </telerik:RadTab>
    <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Tab2" Value="2" PageViewID="PageView2">
    </telerik:RadTab>
  </Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>
<telerik:RadMultiPage id="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">
  <telerik:RadPageView id="PageView1" runat="server">
      ... 1st RadComboBox control here
  </telerik:RadPageView>
  <telerik:RadPageView id="PageView2" runat="server">
      ... 2nd RadComboBox control here
  </telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>     


protected void RadTabStrip1_TabClick(object sender, RadTabStripEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Tab.Value)
  {
    case "1":
      // get a reference of your 1st RadComboBox control and rebind data...
      break;
    case "2": // add a new child tab
      // get a reference of your 2nd RadComboBox control and rebind data...
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: The RadTabStrip and RadComboBox objects are on different web pages.  The RadTabStrip is on the "main" page and the RadComboBox is on another webpage, but displayed on the "main" page when the user selects a certain tab.  Is it possible to "get a reference of your 1st RadComboBox control and rebind data" when the RadComboBox and RadTabStrip controls are on different web pages?

Comment: @MatthewWalk if "another webpage" you meant is an external ASPX page, then perhaps you could consider passing in the Tab value via query string parameter and put in your ajax request URL. if you meant an external ASCX control page, then you could create a public property on the control and assign that tab value to it in your Main page.